# How to fix time of my computer?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, multi-boot

I have laptop with dual boot(windows 8.1 pro + Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).
when windows turned on after Ubuntu being in use, its time will change which become prior to the current time by 2 hours.
For example: if the current time is 4:30 PM it became 2:30 PM
and it is synchronized with the internet time.
So why this happens? and how to fix that?

Comment: Which internet time server is it syncronised to?

Comment: I have tried three different ones:
time-a.nist.gov
time-b.nist.gov
time.windows.com

Comment: Are both systems on the same timezone?

Comment: This is a long-standing problem with dual-boot systems: each realises independently that daylight-saving time has changed since the last boot and makes the adjustment. Either your internet time settings are wrong on one or other system, or synchronisation is set to be done too infrequently - weekly is fine for clock drift, but not for this situation. I don't know if it's still true, but Windows used to change the real-time clock, whereas Unix applied a software offset: you can check the time in your BIOS to see if the clock has changed. I suspect it has.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Excellent reference, thanks. Brings me up to date!

Answer (score -2):

You can set the clock to sync time with NTP servers to avoid this problem.

Comment: time-a.nist.gov,  time-b.nist.gov,  time.windows.com, time.nist.gov, time-nw.nist.gov ==> only those servers I have, I don't have NTP server

Comment: Those are all NTP servers....

Comment: The issue isn't a clock drift, it it just the different ways Windows and Linux handle the real-time clock, see link provided at top.